# Get last hours records in select statement

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a table of machines in which I will display in the first row the actual scrap, in the second row the scrap from last 1 hour, in the third row the scrap from last 4 hours and in the last row the scrap from last 8 hours.

I thought to create in SSRS 4 Datasets for each hours needed. But I think there is a easier way to do it in one Dataset.

Can I do it in the select statement for each hour per one expression?

Comment: We might need to see some fake data or a layout to be more exact. But it sounds like you need each row to be a seperate column, i.e. ActualScrap, LastHourScarp, FourHourScrap, etc. How these are populated (subquery or a cross apply to the same table with different date parms) will vary depending on the data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your question, your select statement needs to be filtered to the last 8 hours. You can then add a new column for which "Type" it is - last hour, last four hours, last 8 hours. Then group by this in a tablix in SSRS.